# Save value of dropdown categories lists in Visual Composer (WPBakery)

Tags: drop-down-menu

I'm stuck on a problem and don't know how to solve it.

This is my code

```
$categories_array = array( __( 'All Categories', 'js_composer' ) => 'mp-all-categories' );
$category_list = get_terms( 'download_category', array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );

    if ( is_array( $category_list ) && ! empty( $category_list ) ) {
        foreach ( $category_list as $category_details ) {   
            $begin = __(' (ID: ', 'js_composer');
            $end = __(')', 'js_composer');
            $categories_array[ $category_details->name . $begin. $category_details->term_id . $end ] = $category_details->term_id;  
        }
    }


 vc_map( array(
   ...
   "params" => array(    
    array(
        'type' => 'dropdown',
        'heading' => __( 'Select Category', 'js_composer' ),
        'param_name' => 'mp_category',
        'value' => $categories_array,           
        'description' => __( 'Select a category', 'js_composer' ),
    ),
```

And this is the code I'm having problems with

```
if( $categories_array != 'mp-all-categories' ) {
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy'           => 'download_category',
            'field'              => 'term_id',
            'terms'              => $categories_array
            //'terms'            => '23',

        );
```

The `$categories_array` doesn't seem to work.

When I select a category from the list, no posts show up while I know there are posts inside the category. Anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this question was extremely easy. I should've used the param name instead. :)

```
if( $mp_category != '' ) {
            $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy'           => 'download_category',
                'field'              => 'term_id',
                'terms'              => $mp_category

            );
          }
```