# Output images from a form

Tags: php

I'd like to display images that have been uploaded through a form using Wordpress.

```
$thumbnail = get_post_meta( $download->ID, 'item_thumbnail', true );
$url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail, 'full' );   

echo '<img src="'.$url[0].'">';
```

There was no output. So I did a `var_dump` and the results were

```
array(7) { 
    [0]=> string(3) "106" 
    [1]=> string(3) "100" 
    [2]=> string(2) "97" 
    [3]=> string(2) "93" 
    [4]=> string(2) "87" 
    [5]=> string(2) "84" 
    [6]=> string(2) "80" 
    }
```

I know these numbers are the image id's. The thing is how to I modify my code so all these images are displayed in my page template?

Comment: Are you dump `$thumbnail` variable?

Comment: It's the `$thumbnail` variable, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code Should be:

```
$thumbnail = get_post_meta( $download->ID, 'item_thumbnail', true );

foreach($thumbnail as $key=>$val){
   $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $val, 'full' );   

   echo '<img src="'.$url[0].'">';

}
```

I hope this should be help for you.

Comment: I know this may sound impolite, but you're the only person I can turn to right now. There's another problem I'm having. If you have time, can you have a look at my question and tell me what I do wrong? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362162/save-value-of-dropdown-categories-lists-in-visual-composer-wpbakery#)